# Iteration when uploading CSV file not able to print desired output

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code which I use in order to upload a CSV file.

```
$handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $import="INSERT into matching(date, time, location, epos_id, rbpos_id, type_of_payment, basket_information, user_id, points) values('$data[0]', '$data[1]', '$data[2]', '$data[3]', '$data[4]', '$data[5]', '$data[6]', '$data[7]', '$data[8]')";

    mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID="'.$data[7].'"';
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $id_user = $row['user_id'];
        $phone = $row['phone'];
        echo $name = $row['first_name'];
    }

    mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error()); 
}

fclose($handle);
```

Now, I need to iterate each data on the column `$data[7]`, so I echo the first name of each person who has that user_id, but apparently it's wrong because nothing is printed.

PS. please note that I'm the only one uploading the data, I'm not concerned about security stuff or whatever.

Comment: I guess that the problem lies here: `so i echo the first name of each person who has that user_id..`. I assume that ID is the primary key. So there is only one record with a given ID (primary key).

Comment: yes but there will be different id's in the csv so i need to find the first name for each id..

Comment: does the database receive all of the inserts in the csv?

Comment: yes, it does! it takes all data

Comment: Why are you running the `$import` query twice?

Comment: Any reason why you're not escaping input? Even if you don't care about security, there's a good chance your program isn't working correctly because you're treating data as code.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: it was an error i removed the duplicated query...

Comment: and no not getting any errors..

Comment: Add `var_dump($data[7])`

Comment: i get  string(10) "4171446415" for one row of csv...

Comment: i echo the query and i get: SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID='4171446415'... i suppose it has something to do with the double while... maybe

Answer (score 0):

Done plenty PHP database stuff but not much with mysql. Would have thought the way you've written the select statement with double quotes surrounding the ID string should be the other way round? I.e. use double quotes for the query string enclosing single quotes for the ID value:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID='".$data[7]."'";
```

You might want to try some debugging - like putting print_r($row); into your while loop.

Comment: Is there any relevance in the fact your select uses the column ID but your $row reference is $row['user_id'] ? Are bothe these columns present?

Comment: sorry, meant to say SHould it not be something like $name=$row['first_name']; then echo "Name=$name<br>\n";

Answer (score 0):

I am submitting sample code to read data from the csv file. I have assumed that you have written the precise code for uploading the csv file by using the **move_uploaded_file** command. So my sample code continues from that point.

```
// Set path to CSV file
$csvFile = 'test.csv';
$file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
//fgetcsv($file_handle);//skips the first line while reading the csv file, uncomment this line if you want to skip the first line in csv file
while (!feof($file_handle) )
{
    $csv_data[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
}
fclose($file_handle);

/*echo '<pre>';
print_r($csv_data);
echo '</pre>';*/

foreach($csv_data as $data)
{
    echo "<br>column 1 data = ".$data[0];
    //Your insert will go something like this
    $import="INSERT into matching(date, time, ..) values('".mysql_real_escape_string($data[0])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[1])."',....)";

    mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

For demo only I have only printed the value of the first column only. If you want to know the complete structure of the data array you can do it by uncommenting the **print_r** block. The function **mysql_real_escape_string** will safely insert the csv data into the database table, if you don't use this function there is high possibility that your mysql query can fail if your csv data contains single or double quotes which breaks the query.